# Find the number of true significant digits in the function $ z=\frac{\sin (3 x+0.7 y)}{\mathrm{e}^{0.4 x+0.5 y}} \cdot(7 x+\ln y) $

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, rounding-error

I just start learning about error theory, rounding etc. Concerning the solution, we need to find the absolute error of the function $\Delta_{z^*}$ and then use it to find the number of true significant figures $
\Delta_{z^*} \leq 0,5\cdot10^{n-m+1}$

My doubts and questions:

(1) Do $e$ , $\sin$ ,$\ln$ also induce error into the absolute error of our function? My guess is that yes. My teacher just told me to take up to 3-4 decimals of $e$ **How do we determine how many decimals of $e$ should we take?**

(2) My teacher told me to find $\Delta_{z^*}$  using partial derivates. Personally,for this function, I find it unpractical and tedious. On the comments somebody suggested using Taylor series in Maclaurin form, I do not get how to implement it in this problem. In fact $ \Delta_{z^*}= \left|\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{\partial f(x^*)}{\partial x_i}\right|\Delta_{x_i^*}$ somehow resembles the Taylor expansions. **Is there a more practical method for finding $\Delta_{z^*}$**

> 4. Given $x=8.34 \pm 0.005 ; y=7.2 \pm 0.05$. Calculate $$ z=\frac{\sin (3 x+0.7 y)}{\mathrm{e}^{0.4 x+0.5 y}} \cdot(7 x+\ln y)
>     $$
>    and determine the number of true significant digits in the product.

Comment: Hint: Use Taylor series.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Like expanding $e$ $\sin $and $\ln$?

Comment: Yup, and then one can analyze (i.e., bound) the order of magnitude of the Taylor Remainder term centered at $(x,y)=(8.34, 7.2)$ with $(\Delta x, \Delta y) = \pm(0.005, 0.05)$

Comment: @Zim could you please link me to a textbook or recomend me so literature specialized in this kind of problems. This was my first class and it seems there are a lot of methods and an really confused

Comment: I would probably try reading a numerical analysis book (e.g. Gautschi), although depending on your background you may find a Calculus 2 or 3 book more accessible (I like Taalman/Kohn, but really there are many).

Comment: $x$ has 3 digits accuracy, $y$ 2 digits. Both have about the same influence on the result, so you can only expect 2 accurate digits. It would be compatible to use 3 or 4 digits from $e$. But is that really relevant? One rarely uses the value of $e$ in the evaluation of an exponential. The values used are $\ln2,\ln3,\ln5$ for the reduction of the exponent, and then some rational expression closely related to the Taylor polynomial, but optimized for accuracy over an interval.